# How can I lookup a column value based on a percentage that must match a range specified in the same row as the return value?

Tags: loops, if-statement, google-apps, google-sheets

I am a lecturer and am trying to build a mini grading spreadsheet that based on the points given to a student will calculate a percentage value describing their grade and I now want to assign the appropriate grade to a student's column in Sheet1 so that it reads

```
50%
C-
```

I have created a matrix of the range identifiers and the text value of the grade on Sheet2 which looks like this:

```
    A     B     C
1   A++   95    100
2   A+    90    94.5
3   A     85    89.5
4   A-    80    84.5
5   B+    75    79.5
6   B     70    74.5
7   B-    65    69.5
8   C+    60    64.5
9   C     55    59.5
10  C-    50    54.5
11  D      0    49.5
```

**Column A** holds the string describing the grade, 
**Column B** is the start of the range,
**Column C** is the end of the range for a given grade.

On Sheet1 I run through all the basic calculations which returns me with a single percentage value to match against this matrix, let's call the field of this value `Sheet1!A1` for now.

What I in essence want to do is loop through the rows 1-11 of Sheet2 and do this:

```
IF ( Sheet1!A1 >= Sheet2!B1 AND Sheet1!A1 <= Sheet2!C1 ) THEN RETURN Sheet2!A1
```

Can this be done? I've read through all the supporting documentation and have not been able to find a way to do this yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks for reading,

Jannis

Answer (score 0):

Anand Varma just replied to the same question posted on the Google Forums with the solution so for completeness I will post his answer here as well.

[The original answer on the Google Forums is here.](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!starred/docs/7ZJizpJJhNM)

The solution was using the `INDEX` function with the `MATCH` function inside of it:

```
=INDEX( Sheet2!$A$1:Sheet2!$A$11, MATCH( C41, Sheet2!$C$1:Sheet2!$C$11, -1 ) )
```

`C41` refers to the cell that holds the numerical source value to match against.

Thanks Anand.